# Variance With Martingales Problem - Answered; Ignore the Bounty

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, martingales

Let $(X_{j})_{j \geq 1}$ be random variables such that $X_{j}$ is $\mathcal{F}$-measurable for each $j$, where $(F_{j})_{j\geq 1}$ is an increasing sequence of $\sigma$-algebras. Assume $E(X_{j}|\mathcal{F}_{j-1})=0$ and $V_{j}=E(X_{j}^{2}|\mathcal{F_{j-1}})$ for $j \geq 2$. Finally, let $s_{n}^{2}=\sum_{j=1}^{n}V_{j}$ for $n \geq 2$, $\tilde{s}_{j}=\max(s_{j},1)$, and $Y_{n}=\sum_{j=2}^{n}\frac{X_{j}}{\tilde{s}_j}$ is a martingale for the sequence of $\sigma$-algebras $(\mathcal{F}_{j})_{j\geq1}$.

Show that $Var(Y_{n})=E(\sum_{j=2}^{n}\frac{V_{j}}{\tilde{s}_{j}^{2}})$

Comment: For a start, were you able to show that E[Y_n]=0? If not, what did you try to show this and where were you stopped?

Comment: I set up the $Var(Y_{n})=E\{Y_{n}^{2}\}-E\{Y_{n}\}^{2}=E\{\left(\sum_{j=2}^{n}\frac{X_{j}}{\tilde{s}_{j}}\right)^{2}\}-\left(E\{\sum_{ j=2}^{n}\frac{X_{j}}{\tilde{s}_{j}}\}\right)^{2}$, and then tried to expand out the term on the left. Basically, what I got there was something like this: $\frac{X_{2}^{2}}{\tilde{s}_{2}^{2}}+\cdots+\frac{X_{n}^{2}}{\tilde{s}_{n}^{2}}+\frac{2X_{2}X_{3}}{\tilde{s}_{2}\tilde{s}_{3}}+\cdots+\frac{2X_{2}X_{n}}{\tilde{s}_{2}\tilde{s}_{n}}+\cdots+\frac{2X_{n-1}X_{n}}{\tilde{s}_{n-1}\tilde{s}_{n}}$. (Continued below)

Comment: Then, I applied the linearity of the expectation and grouped all the squared terms together; I think that's what's going to give me my $V_{j}$ in the numerator. Therefore, I'm assuming that all the other terms must be zero, but I'm not sure why - unless it has something to do with the fact that we assumed $E(X_{j}|\mathcal{F}_{j-1})=0$. Although, I am not sure how to justify that this is indeed the case with all the cross terms. Could you please explain it to me? Then, I figure the same principle would make the squared expectation term on the right that you alluded to be zero as well.

Comment: The part of the question after "Now completed" was posted after a full answer to the part before it was posted. THIS IS NOT THE WAY THE SITE IS SUPPOSED TO WORK. Please revert to the previous version (and post a new question on a new page, if you wish).

Comment: Sorry. Since it was an offshoot of the original question, I wasn't sure how to handle it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For every $n$, let $Z_n=(\tilde s_n)^{-1}X_n$. Here are the pieces you need to solve the problem:

- First, $s_n^2$ is $F_{n-1}$-measurable hence $\tilde s_n$ is $F_{n-1}$-measurable. Thus,
  $$
  E[Z_n\mid F_{n-1}]=(\tilde s_n)^{-1}E[X_n\mid F_{n-1}]=0.
  $$
  Integrating this, one gets
  $$
  E[Z_n]=0.
  $$
- Second, for every $n\lt k$, $\tilde s_k$ and $Z_n$ are $F_{k-1}$-measurable hence
  $$
  E[Z_nZ_k\mid F_{k-1}]=(\tilde s_k)^{-1}Z_nE[X_k\mid F_{k-1}]=0.
  $$
  Integrating this, one gets
  $$
  E[Z_nZ_k]=0.
  $$
- Third, for every $n$, $\tilde s_n$ is $F_{n-1}$-measurable hence
  $$
  E[Z_n^2\mid F_{n-1}]=(\tilde s_n)^{-2}E[X_n^2\mid F_{n-1}]=(\tilde s_n)^{-2}V_n.
  $$
  Integrating this, one gets
  $$
  E[Z_n^2]=E[(\tilde s_n)^{-2}V_n].
  $$

Comment: Did, could you please explain how we know that $s_{n}^{2}$ is $\mathcal{F}_{n-1}$ measurable? Thanks!

Comment: Just spot the measurability of the Vs.